# SQL first occurrence of a string

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a query which returns results like

- Jim 456
- Joe 567
- Joe 789
- Jane 456

What I want to do is have 456 only appear once and take the first name (Jim).

Query looks like

```
select 
     p.id_id as num_id, p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  p.LAST_NAME as Name_
from DWH.V_TABLE p
where p.id_id > 100
```

The reasons for this is I need each to have only one owner, not two

Comment: How are you deciding which reocrd is the "First" one. Why does Jim win over Jane?

Comment: Because they are the first occurance, as in, the first row that is encountered in 'dwh.v_table' @Declan_K

Comment: How can you tell that? Rows is a SQL table are unordered. Is there a date field or some other identifier that tell you that Jim is First? The fact that his name apprear first in the result set is no indication that that record was created first or that it has any precendence over Jane's record.

Comment: @Declan_K In this table the primary owner appears earlier in the table first

Comment: Unless you have a createddate field or some other identifier that confirms that Jim's record was created prior to Jane's then **there is no way to guarantee** that the statement you are making is true.

Comment: @Declan_K To simplify my query, let's say, I just need one person to take ownership of each result so that they can work on an assigned task. It doesn't matter which of the id's owners it is, but this way, someone will get ownership. In this way, it's not really important which get filtered out

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id_id as num_id,
   p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  p.LAST_NAME as Name_
        from DWH.V_TABLE p
         where p.id_id>100
   LIMIT 1
```

Does that what you need? It will return only the first result. Also see [SQL Limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Comment: the issue here is i need to limit 456 to one occurance, not the whole table

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above The ask is now **I just need one person to take ownership of each result so that they can work on an assigned task. It doesn't matter which of the id's owners it is**

the following Query will meet that need.

```
select  p.id_id as num_id
        ,MIN(p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  p.LAST_NAME) as Name_
from    DWH.V_TABLE p
where   p.id_id > 100
GROUP BY
        p.id_id
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work. I still received the duplicates. Maybe cause it's a string and not a number used with 'min' @Declan_K

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "456" is the value stored in the `id_id` column, then this should do it:

```
select num_id, 
       name_
from (
      select p.id_id as num_id,  
             p.first_name || ' ' ||  p.last_name as name_
             row_number() over (partition by p.id_id order by p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  p.LAST_NAME) as rn 
      from dwh.v_table p
      where p.id_id > 100 
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and the question
Presuming you have a date field to check the real owner, or you can filter the records based on their occurrence in anothertable, I'd say that if you just want to get rid of the duplicates for the ID, use the "distinct" keyword.

```
select distinct p.id_id as num_id, p.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  p.LAST_NAME as Name_
from DWH.V_TABLE p
where p.id_id > 100
```

You can also make a self join table (table join to self using p.id_id) and filter the results where "First".name<"Second".name, "First" and "Second" being the aliases of the same table output. (This is only for the case, if you have any sorting criteria base on alphabetical precedence)